# scala - using map function to concatenate JValue

Tags: json, scala, function, json4s

I've recently started using Scala and probably missing something about the map function. I understand that it returns a new value resulting from applying the given function.

For example I have an array of JValues and want to concatenate each value in the array with another JValue or just transform it to a String as in an example below.

```
val salesArray = salesJValue.asInstanceOf[JArray]
val storesWithSales = salesArray.map(sale => compact(render(sale)) //Type mismatch here
val storesWithSales = salesArray.map(sale => compact(render(sale) + compact(render(anotherJvalue))) //Type mismatch here
```

As I can see there is a Type mismatch because the actual value is a String and expected is JValue. Even if I do `compact(render(sale).asInstanceOf[JValue]` it's not allowed to cast string to JValue. Is it possible to return a different type from a map function? And how can I process the array values to transform each of them to another type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the type signature of the `map` method:

```
def map(f: JValue => JValue): JValue
```

So it's a bit different than other `map` methods in that you must specify a function whose return type is `JValue`. This is because a `JArray` represents specifically a deserialized JSON tree, and cannot hold arbitrary objects or data, only `JValue`s.

If you want to process each of the values of a `JArray`, call `.children` on it first. That gives you a `List[JValue]` which then has a more general `map` method since `List`s can hold any type. Its type signature is:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): List[B]
```

So you can do:

```
val storesWithSales = salesArray.children.map(sale => compact(render(sale)))
```